# Bijective concave function from reals to reals

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

I'm looking for an unbounded function $f(x)$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\frac{\textrm{d} f}{\textrm{d} x} > 0\quad\textrm{and}\quad
\frac{\textrm{d}^{2} f}{\textrm{d} x^{2}} < 0.
$$
I was able to come up with
$$
f(x) = \log\Big(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}\Big) - \Big[ x^{2} - x\sqrt{x^{2}+1} \Big],
$$
but are there simpler such functions?

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158452/830080), but I don't want the function to be asymptotically linear.

Comment: This one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3158509/42969 is not asymptotically linear.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I know I didn't mention it, but if I could avoid piecewise functions it would be ideal