# I'm searching for a monotonically increasing function, defined for all reals, that is concave down and a "gentle curve" (no aymptotes).

Tags: functions

I'm searching for a monotonically increasing function, defined for all reals, that is concave down and a "gentle curve" (no aymptotes). The link below provides an image:

[example of gentle concave down curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POhKF.jpg)

This post has some examples of near misses: [Is there a bijective, monotonically increasing, strictly concave function from the reals, to the reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158452/is-there-a-bijective-monotonically-increasing-strictly-concave-function-from-t)

For instance: y = -e^(-x)

However, this is not by any means a gentle curve, outside of the domain (-3,3). The rest of the graph looks essentially like a right angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try something like
$$
f(x) := -\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+4}}{4}+\operatorname{asinh}\frac{x}{2}
\tag1$$
[image: a]

We have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty,\quad \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0,
\\
\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -\infty,\quad \lim_{x\to-\infty} f'(x) = -\infty,
$$

To find this, I started with the hyperbola $y(y+x)=1$ with asymptotes $y=0$ to the right and $y=-x$ to the left.  But you said you did not want asymptotes.  So I integrated it,
$$
\int \left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\right) \,dx
$$
to get $(1)$.

Comment: Your method for deriving the function makes sense, GEdgar.  That said, a zoomed-out graph of the function still looks a little "right-angle-ish":  https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4kgE.png.  Its the best I have so far, but I'm curious if there are even gentler curves to be found.  

Admittedly, I suppose that every "gentle curve" looks right-angle-ish if you zoom the scale out far enough, perhaps!  I would guess that by playing around with the parameters of GEdgar's equation I could "broaden" the "gentle portion" of the curve.